# How to deploy a single solution with multiple projects?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a well-decoupled website using WebAPI and AngularJS as follows:

```
SOLUTION
  |—— WEB.API Project  
  |—— Website pages Project
  '—— Other projects related to functionalities
```

This setup is on my own computer.

Now I'm here wanting to deploy to my web server (iis 7.5, privately owned, WebDeploy installed). It is possible to deploy both projects on a single web site? (other projects are class libraries, so no hassle)

For what I know, I have to deploy the WebAPI part to a website, and the UI part to another website. May I put them on a single website?

Comment: Aren't you running your apps locally on IIS as well? It would make it much simpler to deploy as the whole scenario will be very very similar between development and production environment.

Comment: Why do you need to split them? Will the Web API be used by other clients?

Comment: Exactly as stated by @christiandev, I need to consume the json in other scenarios, like mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also *self-host* the Web API using [OWIN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api), so you wouldn't then need to set up a project in IIS etc and you could then have multiple clients talking to the same API.

There's a tutorial [`here`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869223/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Create-a-Self-Hosted-OWIN-Based-We) which is more advanced.

Comment: ok, I'll accept this as answer, because using this way I can host both project outside IIS. For a simple html based website I don't need all the bloat that come with it, and self host the Web.Api will be a killer for performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the Web API project in a virtual directory under the main web site. That's what we are actually doing in our current project.

Comment: This was helpful, but we moved different way.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you should be worried when files conflict. If both projects have a `web.config` for example, this could break either of them.

If not, it should be possible, but I wouldn't immediately recommend it. I would split them off in separate virtual directories so you can maintain the two separate projects easily.

Comment: Virtual directory shares the same app pool. I want to use an app pool for the web api and no app pool or other extension for some html pages

Comment: Then make it an application. Right click on the folder in IIS and select Convert to Application.

Answer (score 1):

I have a near identical project setup. Personally I picked 2 separate apps, I have a multi server setup with load balancers - the choice may have been different if I had a single server or low amount of expected traffic.

**This gives the advantage:**
I expected my WebAPI to have a larger amount of traffic than the web pages, due to mobile clients also consuming the WebAPI as well as the front end webpages. Because the API is in its own website, it has its own app pool - this means that each application has its own resource pool (app can grow to use more memory and CPU better), not shared like they would be on a virtual directory.

**Disadvantages:**
Because there is two separate app pools, I have one bound to port 80 and the other to port 8080. As I had a large server farm to roll this out on, I already had a load balancer in front of the webservers - hence to make the URL pretty (i.e. drop the port 8080 from the URL) i added a load balancer config to allow traffic to come in on a given url on port 80 and be redirected to port 8080 on the internal webservers. This isn't really a issue if you don't mind ports in your URL's.

Comment: and why not two separate dns entries? You (and I of course) may have something like rest.example.com for the web.api project and www.example.com for the frontend

Comment: Hi @Valerio yes this is exactly what I have, but without the load balancer config you would still be left with the port number in the url of the dns entry. As i said not a problem if you don't mind it, but i always think its a little messy hence why i added the load balancer config.